# Fitting an arbitrary function to measurements with x and y errors

Tags: python, curve-fitting

As a physicist, my measurement data almost always has x and y errors. I can fit functions like `a x^2 \exp(-b x^2)` to it using gnuplot or `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` in Python. The fit error I get for `a` and `b` in both programs only gives me the grade of the fit, not the actual error of `a` and `b`.

So although I have a covariance matrix, it does not change when I double the `y`-errors. In the lab manual, it shows how to do weighted linear fits and giving the error correctly.

Is there a software package than does more than just weighting with the `y`-error? I could roll my own, implementing the formulas from the manual and transforming all data to get a linear fit. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, how can I flag it?

Comment: Click on the gray "flag" underneath the tag for "measurement-error".

Comment: Done, I added a flag.

Comment: I think that the measurement errors are used as *relative* weights.  If you double them all, it shouldn't change the uncertainty in your `a` and `b`, but it should scale the chi squared (or other goodness of fit parameter).

Comment: Fitting a constant model function to data will give a weighted mean as a fit parameter. I expect the error of that fit parameter to increase when I increase the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now, a couple things have changed. There is the [linfit](https://github.com/djpine/linfit) package which does this. The SciPy function `curve_fit` now has the `absolute_sigma` option which will take the error in `x` into account.

However, I have circumvented the whole problem by using the bootstrap method to estimate my errors now. This involves a lot of fits to different selections of the data.